# undefined local variable or method `password' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following [this](https://www.devmedia.com.br/ruby-on-rails-implementando-autenticacao-de-usuario/32124) tutorial and got stuck on the validate part.

I followed the tutorial step by step, but when I try to create the virtual attribute that will receive the password, I get the following error: `undefined local variable or method 'password' for User`.

Here's my:

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    validates name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    validates password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
    VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT= /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
    validates email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 260}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase, :set_default }

    def set_default
        self.comissaoAcumuladaAtual = 0 unless self.comissaoAcumuladaAtual
        self.comissaoASerRetirada = 0 unless self.comissaoASerRetirada
    end
end
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect to @user, notice: "Cadastro realizado com sucesso."
      #sign_in(@user)
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :tipoPlano, :valorPlano, :indicadoPor)
  end
end
```

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
            <% if @user.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
                        <div class="alert-error">
                                   O formulário contém <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "erro") %>.
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                                   <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                   <li><%= msg %></li>
                                   <% end %>
                        </ul>
            </div>
<% end %>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :name %>
                <%= f.text_field :name %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email %>
                <%= f.email_field :email %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <%= f.password_field :password %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :tipoPlano%>
                <%= f.text_field :tipoPlano%>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :valorPlano%>
                <%= f.number_field  :valorPlano, step: 0.01%>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                        <%= f.submit "Cadastrar"%>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  get    'sign_in'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'sign_in'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'sign_out'  => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

I seriously have no idea what to do. I've been thinking about this for at least 1 hour and I can't seem to make it works. Do I need to define the virtual attribute elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validates method expects the first argument to be a `Symbol`.

Just change

```
validates name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
validates password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
validates email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 260}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

to

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 260}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_FORMAT}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

Comment: Oh wow. It worked. Thanks, mate. I feel really dumb now lol